# rspec expect change to created object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I test `current_accreditation` changing in the controller action. `current_accreditation` is similar to the `current_user`, `current_locale` and other similar methods.

```
it { expect{subject}.to change(controller.current_accreditation).from(@legal).to( assigns(:contractor).legal ) }
```

Here is controller code.

```
def create
  @contractor = Contractor.restrict!(current_accreditation).new(permitted_params) # TODO move to the IR::Base
  if @contractor.save
    sign_accreditation @contractor.create_legal!(user: current_user)
    redirect_to(@contractor)
  else
    render(:new)
  end
end
```

It seems, `assign(:contractor)` return `nil`, because of it take `@contractor` variable before `create` method start. How can I avoid that? How can I pass to `to` method values which will create in it? I tried lambda but have no arguments error. I also tried something like `Accreditation.last`, but I can't find created accreditation too.

Answer (score -1):

For starters, you're not using the `change` matcher as documented in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher.  `change` takes either: a) a block or b) an object and an attribute. You're passing in a single argument.

In the case of passing in a block, it evaluates the block before and after. In the case of an object and an attribute, it evaluates the attribute of the object before and after. With just an object being passed in, it has nothing to evaluate.

So, specifically, you can use either:

```
it { expect{subject}.to change(controller, :current_accreditation).from(@legal).to( assigns(:contractor).legal ) }
```

or

```
it { expect{subject}.to change { controller.current_accreditation }.from(@legal).to( assigns(:contractor).legal ) }
```

Comment: Tried that: 

`expect{subject}.to change{ controller.current_accreditation }.from(@legal).to( assigns(:contractor).try(:legal) )` but with no success

Comment: Another way don't work too. Undefined method legal for nil::NilClass